# Resultado de iteracion de array en una variable

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, random

Hola lo que quiero es obtener una valor random almacenado en una variable despues de iterar un array bucleado 10 veces.

El código que he hecho solo me tira una letra.

Si alguno me puede dar una mano con esto, estaría agradecido.

Saludos.

```
var palos = ["Trebol","Picas","Corazon","Diamantes"];
var combi=[];
for(var i = 0; i<palos.length; i++){
   for(var j=1; j<=10; j++){ 
       combi = combi + (" - Carta: "+j+" de "+palos[i]);
   }
}
var random = combi[Math.floor(Math.random() + combi.length)]
console.log(random)
```

Comment: Que array quieres buclear 10 veces?

Comment: ¿POdrías subir el código que has hecho para ver si encontramos el fallo?

Comment: el codigo esta como escondido, al editarlo lo he visto

Comment: Si lo has visto al editar, ¿Por qué no lo arreglas para que todos podamos verlo? no permite editar si alguien está editando.

Comment: El problema es que no se ha aprobado todavía mi edición. He reportado mi respuesta ya que no se si lo que he hecho es del todo legal.

Comment: No te preocupes! aquí se busca ayudar al usuario no conseguir puntos :)

Comment: Una recomendación que te doy para formular las preguntas en StackOverflow es que especifiques el código diferenciándolo de la pregunta en cuestión haciendo uso de "Ejemplo de código". Aparece en la parte superior del recuadro para rellenar la duda. De esta forma, tu código será más legible

Answer (score 2):

Tienes el error al crear el array de cartas en:

```
combi = combi + (" - Carta: "+j+" de "+palos[i])
```

Estás concatenando un string. Entonces combi se convierte en un string con todas las cartas concatenadas. Para crear el array tienes que ir añadiendo:

```
 combi.push( " - Carta: "+j+" de "+palos[i]);
```

Esto te crea el array con todas las cartas.

---

Luego para que te salga un número aleatorio has te multiplicar el random con el máximo al que quieres el random:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * combi.length)
```

Esto te daria un número aleatorio entre 0 y el número de cartas que tiene combi.

---

En conjunto, obtienes:

```js
var palos = ["Trebol","Picas","Corazon","Diamantes"];
var combi=[];
for(var i = 0; i<palos.length; i++){
   for(var j=1; j<=10; j++){ 
       combi.push( " - Carta: "+j+" de "+palos[i]);
   }
}

var random = combi[Math.floor(Math.random() *combi.length)]
console.log(random)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo quiero agregar que tal como parece que está planteado el problema, no sería necesario crear el segundo array:

```js
var palos = ["Trebol","Picas","Corazon","Diamantes"];


var randomPalos = Math.floor(Math.random()*palos.length);  

var randomNumero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;



console.log( " - Carta: "+randomNumero+" de "+palos[randomPalos]);
```